# In angular2 does anyone know how to get angular2-google-maps working or know a similar node module

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

In angular2 does anyone know how to get angular2-google-maps working or know a similar node module.

**This is my current module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

import { SearchJobsComponent } from './searchJobs.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, AgmCoreModule],
  declarations: [SearchJobsComponent],
  exports: [SearchJobsComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class SearchJobsModule { }
```

**This is the error I get:**

> caused by: No provider for MapsAPILoader!
>   No provider for MapsAPILoader!
>       at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:1104)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `.forRoot()` call in your NgModule decorator:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, AgmCoreModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [SearchJobsComponent],
  exports: [SearchJobsComponent],
  providers: []
})
```

Be sure to checkout the setup guide [here](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html#angular2-google-maps-setup).

Comment: Thank you, it worked! what does forRoot() do existly? it looks hacky

Comment: It is angular standard. It does load the module with providers. If you import the module again in child modules you usually call .forChild() so you do not load the providers again.

Answer (score 1):

Like PerfectPixel said, you need to import AgmCoreModule with the .forRoot() call so it imports all the relevant providers as well (like MapsAPILoader for example).

Note that you need to do this once in your root module, and then import AgmCoreModule like you already are in each module that needs its components.